# Is it possible to append (rather than overwrite) cucumberOpt.tagExpressions in the command line?

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

I have selenium tests which run using cucumber and wdio.
My wdio.conf.js file looks like this:

```
cucumberOpts: {
    tagExpression: 'not @ignore',
},
```

I have tests which I have tagged

```
@cats
Scenario: As a user I want to google cats
Given I have google open
When I type in 'cats'
And then I see pictures of cats

@dogs
Scenario: As a user I want to google dogs
Given I have google open
When I type in 'dogs'
And then I see pictures of dogs

@dogs @ignore
Scenario: As a user I want to google fierce dogs
Given I have google open
When I type in 'fierce dogs'
And then I see pictures of fierce dogs
```

If I want to run all dogs tests which haven't been ignored I can run:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@dogs and not @ignore'
```

What I would like to be able to do is just run

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@dogs'
```

(or similar) from the command line and have it pick up the 'not @ignore' from the wdio.conf.js file.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible; you do have to write some code for it though. Assuming you have '[yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)' installed, you could do something like:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

let tags = '(not @pending)';

if (argv.tags) {
  tags += ` and (${argv.tags})`
}

// ...rest of configs

cucumberOpts: {
    tagExpression: tags
},
```

Then you'd run it with:
`./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --tags='@dogs'`

Note that I haven't tested this specific code, so hopefully no syntax errors.